# Can we please cleanup this popular question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-quality, popular-questions

This question appears to be quite popular:

- [Why are shortcuts like x += y considered good practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice)

Currently it has over 34K views, making it in [top 250 all time](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A34000) ([top 150](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A34000+closed%3Ano) if we discard closed questions).

As far as I can tell, it managed to attract couple answers of sub-par quality. Can we please do something about these, following [guidance provided in related discussion at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773):

> ...answers that are strong candidates for deletion:
>
> - belong to low rep or anon users with no real commitment to the community
> - are *provably* duplicate, that is, were added well after (30+ mins later) other answers that contained the same exact information
> - are short in length
> - do not explain much of anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just deleted all answers that were not positive scoring (<= 0). I'm debating historical locking it, but I don't think it meets all the criteria for a historical lock. I do wish that there was a "popular, but we don't need to beat a dead horse" lock or a stronger form of question protection.

Comment: I reviewed cleaned up question in logged out mode, to hide deleted answers - it looks okay now. Quality of the answers noticeably varies but this mostly feels... organic. Thanks!